# Unable to clear the Highlighted first cell of DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I want first row cell of DGV to be not selected, Whenever my application initializes. I'm using the following code, but it only works when I disable Timer (I really don't know the reason).

```
 private void BindData()
 {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = DeviceData.BindData(BMS_Controls.ClsConstant.DEVICETYPE.PRIMARY_PUMPS.ToString());
                bindingSource1.DataSource = dt;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
                dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }
  }

  private void frmPrimaryPumps_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
            BindData();
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
            timer1.Start();

   }
```

I'm using Timer to call `BindData` method after the wait of 1 second.

Could anyone please tell me how can I disable first row selection, and call the `BindData` method successfully using Timer?

Comment: I have tried this but my results are as expected. The only thing that comes to my mind is the possibility that your grid is editable and set to EditOnEnter, in which case it is not a problem of grid but of edit control.

Answer (score 1):

You should try setting the `datagridview1.CurrentCell = null` after assigning the `DataSource`, this should remove the selection of the first row/cell from your grid.

Comment: i have already used this property.but it does not work. pls give some other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

call

dgv.ClearSelection();

on DataBindingsCompleted event

like following

dgv.DataBindingComplete += new DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(dgv_DataBindingComplete);

```
    private void dgv_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView d = sender as DataGridView;
        d.ClearSelection();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with adding the line you already added:

```
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
```

try removing refresh method.